# Flask sql-alchemy many to many relationship append multi obj at once?

Tags: python, flask, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

At first I define three table

```
registerations = db.Table()

class Student(db.Model):

class Class(db.Model):
```

I can use

```
student.classes.append(class1)
student.classes.append(class2)
student.classes.append(class3)
student.classes.append(class4)
```

to add info in the junction table, and it works well

but My problem is how can I add all classes to the student at once

```
student.classes.somemethod(class1, class2, class3, class4)
```

and is there a method that I can do this>> or I have to write a function by my own..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQLAlchemy handles to-many relationships with a list-like interface. You can use the `append` method to add a single item:

```
student.classes.append(class1)
```

And you can use the `extend` method to add all of the items from an iterable:

```
student.classes.extend([class1, class2, class3, class4])
```

The [SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/collections.html#custom-collection-implementations) talk about which list-like methods are automatically implemented on a collection.

Comment: I can't use add to add a single Item, also I can't use extends to add multi items..only append works

Comment: You're right. It should have been `append`, not `add`.

Comment: What happens when you try to use `extend`? Do you get an error? You need to tell us what specific problem you're having.

Comment: Nothing happens, No error echo out, But the junction table will not update with add or extends...but If I use append the junction table will be updated..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106912/discussion-between-tyan-and-dirn).

Comment: @dim , You are right, I find I use extends instead of extend so it doesn't work.

Comment: Append didn't work for me if the object I insert has id=0. I had to set it to None first.